# Dropdownlist in Cgridview column with ajax load to database

Tags: yii

I got some issue. So basically I'm trying to make dropdownlist in CGridView column to manage statuses. I want to load onchange to database. Here is grid column:

```
array(
        'name'=>'status',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'CHtml::dropDownlist(\'status\',\'\',array(\'1\'=>\'Complete\',
                        \'2\'=>\'Paid\',
        \'3\'=>\'Not paid\'),array(
                                    \'class\'=>\'status\',
                                    \'options\'=>array($data->status=>array(\'selected\'=>\'selected\')),
                                    \'ajax\'=>array(
                                        \'type\' => \'POST\',
                                        \'url\'=>Yii::app()->createUrl(\'user/orders/status\'),                        
                                        \'data\'=>array(\'status\'=>\'js:this.value\',\'order\'=>$data->id),
        )
        ));',
        ),
```

Here is controller action code

```
public function actionStatus()
    {
    if (isset($_POST['order'])){
        $model=$this->loadModel($_POST['order']);
        $model->status=$_POST['status'];        
    $model->save();
      
    }    
    }
```

So what is the problem. I'm getting last $data->id and not id for element which dropdown changed. All other works fine.

Maybe it's easy but I can't find any solution.

Comment: why don't you make use of the  [X-Editable Extension for Yii](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/index). It's should pretty much solve your problem and take out your "spaghetti-code" :D

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. But i rly hope that there is some another way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You can avoid all this ugly escaped code if you use a getter in your model class:

```
public function getStatusDropdown()
{
    $stats = array(
        1 => 'Complete',
        2 => 'Paid',
        3 => 'Not paid',
    );
    return CHtml::dropDownlist('status',$this->status,$stats, array(
        'class'     => 'status',
        'data-id'   => $this->id,
    ));
}
```

Now add a grid column like

```
array(
    'name'  => 'Status',
    'type'  => 'raw',
    'value' => '$data->statusDropdown',
),
```

What's left now is to add some Javascript. Instead of adding a script to each and every button it's much more efficient if you register one snippet to rule them all. You have to listen to the `change` event of all dropdowns. So you could register a inline snippet right on the page with your gridview like this:

```
$url = $this->createUrl('user/orders/status');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initStatus',
    "$('select.status').on('change','body',function() {
        el = $(this);
        $.ajaxPost('$url', {status: el.val(), id: el.data('id')}
    });",
    CClientScript::POS_READY
);
```

I've added a `body` selector to make sure, the event still fires if your GridView is updated through AJAX. You may also want to add a success handler to your `ajaxPost()` call.

Note, that the above may contain typos, so don't just copy and paste but try to understand how it works. It should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this didnt work. I used getter with ajax onchange before. 
  `echo CHtml::dropDownlist('status',$this->status,$status,array(
  'class'=>'status',
   'ajax'=>array(
   'type' => 'POST',
         'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('user/orders/status'),         'data'=>array('status'=>'js:this.value','order'=>$this->id),
  )
  ));
 }`

Comment: But `$this->id` gives me last id and not current. Its the only problem i have.

Comment: I know it *does* work - I user similar techniques all the time in my apps. Did you really try what i posted above? What you describe is still different as you use the `ajax` property. I'd avoid it in this case, because you end up with dozens of almost identical js snippets, where a single snippet like above would be sufficient. It's also easier to debug: You can inspect the source code to see if the right `id` is set for each dropdown in the `data-id` attribute. And you can set a breakpoint in the `change` handler to see what value `el` has.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. It was my mistake. This solution works perfectly. 1 more snippet to collection.

Comment: Very effective solution.Cheers