# yii cgridview dropdownlist column value with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii

Im new to yii. Can anyone find the solution to my problem.where is my mistake. It does not return value. In statuslevel action i have to submit the value to status in another model.

index.php:

```
array(
    'name' => 'status',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => "CHtml::dropDownList('status', '', array('1' => 'Open' , '2' => 'Fixed' , '3' => 'Closed' , '4' => 'Re-Open' , '5' => 'Clarification'),  
    'ajax' => array(
        'type' => 'GET', 
        'data' => array('status' => 'js:this.value'), 
        'dataType' => 'text',
        'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('projectBug/statuslevel'),    
        'success' => 'function(data){alert(data);}',
     ),
     'filter' => false,
),
```

Comment: checkout this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061828/dropdownlist-in-cgridview-column-with-ajax-load-to-database

Comment: You forgot to put `"` at end of `dropDownList` ?

Answer (score -1):

It was just to change the get method to the method `'type' => 'POST'`