# Drop down value from cgrid view in yii

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am getting the data from database

```
$sqlQuery="select receivedJob_id as ID,received_date as DATED,job_title as JOB,location as LOCATION,firstName as FIRSTNAME,lastName as LASTNAME,college as COLLEGE,
            qualification as QUALIFICATION,cpi as CPI,exp_salary as EXP_SALARY,ctc as CTC,notice_period as NOTICE_PERIOD,current_emp as CURRENT_COMPANY from receivedJobs";
    $data=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlQuery)->queryAll();
```

and showing to view in table using array data provider and cgird view,Now I am adding one extra field in table in in controller I have defined the active drop down list like this

```
$actionList=array("shortlist","download Resume","Not interested");
    $dropdown =  CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'taken_action',$actionList,array('empty'=>'Select'));
    $totalrow = count($filteredData);
    for($index=0;$index<$totalrow;$index++){
        $filteredData[$index]['DD'] = $dropdown;
    }
```

and  showing the table in view using cgrid view without any issue,Now on screen if I choose an option from drop down list ,I want to get that selected value to manipulate it,For that I used CCheckBox class like this in view

```
array (
                    'id' => 'selectedId',
                    'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn' 
            ),
```

when i select one row from screen table I can get the id of that row,but how Can I get the drop down selected value for that row?
Any help would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061828/dropdownlist-in-cgridview-column-with-ajax-load-to-database

Comment: @ineersa, Thanks for your solution,I did the changes in module file  as below  
 public function getStatusDropdown()
 {
  $stats = array(
    1 => 'Selected',
    2 => 'Downloaded',
    3 => 'Not Suitable',
  );
  return CHtml::dropDownlist('taken_action',$this->taken_action,$stats, array(
    'class'     => 'taken_action',
    'data-id'   => $this->receivedJob_id,
    
  ));
 }

Comment: and in view as below and in view as below    $url = $this->createUrl('site/employerNotifications');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('inittaken_action',
"$('select.taken_action').on('change','body',function() {
el = $(this);
$.ajaxPost('$url', {taken_action: el.val(), receivedJob_id: el.data('receivedJob_id')}
});",
CClientScript::POS_READY
);, but it's not working for me,Can you please provide more details ,i am new to yii.